# Need to match two SQL tables based on dates but I need to check for date+1

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I'm fairly new to SQL (~9 months or so) and so I'm stumped trying to figure out this problem, using SQL Server 2012.

I'm trying to match up two tables that look like this:

Table `Shift`:

```
    Date       |    Name    | Shift
    01-01-2013 | Dan Smith  | Night
    01-02-2013 |John Johnson| Night
    01-03-2013 |John Johnson| Night
```

Table `Sales`:

```
    Date       |    Name    | Sales
    01-01-2013 | Dan Smith  | 3
    01-02-2013 | Dan Smith  | 5
    01-02-2013 |John Johnson| 4
    01-03-2013 |John Johnson| 7
    01-04-2013 |John Johnson| 2
```

The issue is that the shift table only includes the start date of the shift, which is problematic for the night shift as it takes place over two days. Sales for the night shift show up as taking place over both days as they are timestamped when they occur. This means that if I simply try to link the tables based on the Name and Shift Date, and the person does not have a shift the next day, I will miss any sales data from 12:00AM onward. I'm searching for a way to check if the person has a shift the next day, and if not, add their sales data for the next day to the previous days sales.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
Select
   st.Name,
   st.Date,
   st.Shift,
   sl.Sales
From 
   Shift st
right join 
   Sales as sl on sl.Name = st.Name
               and sl.Date = Case
                               When sl.Date = DATEADD(DD, 1, st.Date)
                               Then DATEADD(DD,1, st.Date)
                               Else st.Date
                             End
```

Which picks up the missing data from when I simply used sales.date=shift.date, but it also ends up with a lot of duplicate data. Apologies if this is simple, but I haven't been able to figure out a good way to simply check if the salesperson doesn't have a shift the next day and then adding the next days sales data for that person to their previous days.

edit: Desired results would look something like this:

```
ShiftDate  |    Name    | Shift | Sales
01-01-2013 | Dan Smith  | Night | 8
01-02-2013 |John Johnson| Night | 4
01-03-2013 |John Johnson| Night | 9
```

I don't really mind if the precise per-shift sales numbers aren't 100% accurate, but I do need to pick up the next day sales data if they don't have a shift the next day.

I would love a model change as it would absolutely fix this problem and have been working to get one for a while now. Unfortunately, the sales data comes from an outside source which I then import into our database, and they so far have been unwilling/unable to provide the precise timestamps.

Comment: Yakshemash ! You are not a new anymore. I only do SQL for a 3 month :) Your DB needs to include all timestamps.

Comment: Can you post what's the desired result?

Comment: How can we know how to assign the sales made by John Johnson the `01-03-2013`?, you are showing it to the `01-03-2013` shift, but it could also be the `01-02-2013` by your own rules

Comment: You can't, which is why I was hoping to find a way to simply aggregate based on the sales day unless it is the last shift in a row for the person in which case it adds it to the previous day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this works as you intended:

```
;WITH Sales2 AS
(
    SELECT A.*, CASE WHEN B.[Date] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END LastShift
    FROM Sales A
    LEFT JOIN Sales B
      ON A.Name = B.Name
      AND A.[Date] = DATEADD(DAY,-1,B.[Date])
)
SELECT  A.[Date],
        A.Name,
        A.Shift,
        SUM(B.Sales) Sales
FROM Shift A
LEFT JOIN Sales2 B
  ON A.Name = B.Name
  AND CASE 
        WHEN A.Shift <> 'Night' AND A.[Date] = B.[Date] 
            THEN 1
        WHEN A.Shift = 'Night' AND B.LastShift = 0 AND A.[Date] =  B.[Date]
            THEN 1 
        WHEN A.Shift = 'Night' AND B.LastShift = 1 AND A.[Date] = DATEADD(DAY,-1,B.[Date]) 
            THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
      END = 1
GROUP BY A.[Date],
         A.Name,
         A.Shift
```

[**Here is a sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ad332/2) with a demo of this solution.

And the resuls are:

```
╔═════════════════════════╦══════════════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║          Date           ║     Name     ║ Shift ║ Sales ║
╠═════════════════════════╬══════════════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║ 2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 ║ Dan Smith    ║ Night ║     8 ║
║ 2013-01-02 00:00:00.000 ║ John Johnson ║ Night ║     4 ║
║ 2013-01-03 00:00:00.000 ║ John Johnson ║ Night ║     9 ║
╚═════════════════════════╩══════════════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

You have model problems. I suggest you define another table that defines the actual start and finish dates. YOu will be able to use that table to place the sales in the right dates and to the corresponding shift.

Comment: If only! The sales data comes from an outside source (don't ask) which I then import into our db and they have not been/are not willing to/do not have the capacity to provide precise timestamps. It's a problem I've been trying to fix for months but probably won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need a better model. See if this works?

```
SELECT  
    sft.Name,
    sft.Date,
    sft.Shift,
    sum(sls.Sales)       
FROM Sales sls  
LEFT JOIN Shift sft
   ON sls.Date >= sft.Date
WHERE  (sls.Date = sft.Date OR sls.Date NOT IN   
        (SELECT Date FROM Shift WHERE Date = sls.Date AND Name = sls.Name ))
GROUP BY 
    sft.Name,
    sft.Date,
    sft.Shift
```

Comment: Invalid column name 'Sales'. Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev Thanks I've made some changes.

Comment: ON sls.Date >= sft.Sales - Invalid column name 'Sales'.

Comment: now it has some output. don't know if that is what the op wants.